# How to get another field from the database by entering data?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I created the following using VB.net and MS Access. Here While I enter the book title in the text box it automatically sort the value in the datagrid view.
[image: Datagrid filterd by textbox value]

Code

```
 Private Sub frmBookSearch_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtBookSearch.Focus()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [BookID], [Title], [Author], [Publisher], [Category], [Price], [ISBN] FROM tblBooks", myConnection)
    da.Fill(ds, "tblBooks")
    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

End Sub

Private Sub txtBoxNo_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtBookSearch.KeyPress
    source1.Filter = String.Format("[Title] LIKE'" & txtBookSearch.Text & "%'")
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Now I am creating another app using BV.Net and SQL server.
Here I want to Fill the member name text box while entering the member ID in the member ID text box, and fill book name text box while entering the book Acc no textbox.

Table details as follows

```
tblMember
-----------
membershipNo INT
firstName    VARCHAR (50)


tblBookDetail
------------
 accessionNo INT
 title VARCHAR(300)
```

[image: SQL Server and VB.Net]

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub txtMemID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtMemID.TextChanged
    Using comBookLendMember As New SqlCommand("SELECT membershipNo, firstName FROM tblMember ORDER BY membershipNo", con)

    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: run the query, get the result, set the contents of the textbox as the values from the relevant columns. I can see from the code that you certainly know how to do the first part, and the other parts are pretty easy to google. Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Why would the Book Lend thing be different than the first thing?  Load a datasource for each and filter them accordingly.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: The first is book search. That is old one. Other one is new, that is for Lending book.

Comment: So what?  Arent they both just common ordinary look ups?  You apparently think the book search is the same in some ways or you wouldnt have included it here

Comment: Yes, I just added the sql command. and how to do the next part. Please

Comment: Look carefully at your first code - it does not build a new query in TextChanged - it loads a datasource when the form loads, then just filters it when they type.  Do that.  The difference is that you have 2 DataSources to manage - one for Books and one for Members.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: But how to select from the database with the value of memberID or Book ID ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].